# deep look at Internal storage in android

Tags: android, internal-storage

I have written a simple app which has only one `MainActivity`. 
`MainActivity` has only `ListView` and simple `ArrayAdapter` which displays integers.
When the user click `add` button from menu - one more value added onto `listView` and *all integers are saved in file*.
When the user click `delete`,as expected, one value deleted from `listview`
**But** *nothing done to file*.
Here is a full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<Integer> list;
    private static final String fileName = "any_path";
    private int ADD_ID = 0;
    private int DELETE_ID = 1;
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        load();
        ListView view = new ListView(this);
        setContentView(view);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, ADD_ID,1, "Add");
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID,0, "Delete");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == ADD_ID) { // if add was clicked
            adapter.add(adapter.getCount());
            save(); // SAVING HAPPENS HERE
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == DELETE_ID) { 
            list.remove(list.size()-1);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true; // NOTHING DONE TO FILE
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        save();
    }
    private void save() {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        for (int el:list) {
            array.put(el);
        }
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            OutputStream out = this.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
            writer.write(array.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
    private void load() {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = this.openFileInput(fileName);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                data.append(line);
            }
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray)new JSONTokener(data.toString()).nextValue();
            for (int i=0;i<array.length(); i++)
                list.add(array.getInt(i));
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but i don't understand how values are magically removed from file.
To be more exact:
    1)User has clicked `add` five times, so '0 1 2 3 4' will be saved in file:
2)User has clicked `delete` two times, so list will be `0 1 2` but *nothing happens to file*
3)If i restart an app i see `0 1 2`, instead of `0 1 2 3 4`
Why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The save() is also called in onStop() when you close the app:

```
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    save();
}
```

So when it contains 0,1,2,3 then it will restart with it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should update (reload) data to `listview` and set it again after removing, because with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` you inform adapter, but data is already there, it would work if you remove from `listview` directly.
So you should directly just reload data.
Hope it helps.

**UPDATED:**

I thought you want to make it backwards.. I don't see if you closed `InputStream` and `OutputStream`. Usually it happens because of that.

Comment: `Everything works fine`, i just don`t understand *how* data removed in internal storage (in file) if i don't delete it.